# display and hide text using hover in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a simple functionality using the hover property in jQuery. When I hover on the div, some text must be displayed in the span element. That is pretty much the concept.

```
<script>
    $(".logo").hover( 
        function() { $("#span_hover").html("Please visit http://www.gmu.edu for more information.") }, 
        function() { $("#span_hover").html(""); } );
</script>
    <div class="logo"><a href="http://www.gmu.edu/"><img src="images/GMU_logo" height="100" width="150" /></a></div>
    <span id="span_hover" style="position:fixed; bottom:5px; right:150px;"></span>
```

This code is not working! Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Wrap your javascript with `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: tried it. Did not work

Comment: On the moment of call `$(".logo")` you div with `.logo` does not exit. That is why you have to run this code when DOM is loaded or below the part of the page with needed div.  `tried it. Did not work` show it.

Comment: Did you forgot to load jQuery? See working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/8as30y06/

Comment: @Cheery : are you saying that I have to put my javascript after the html code?

Comment: @SriRamGopal either below the part in html where all your elements are set or use, as everybody is telling you, the `$(document).ready()` to run your code when html code of the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".logo").hover(
        function() { 
            $("#span_hover").html("Please visit http://www.gmu.edu for more information.");
        }, 
        function() {
            $("#span_hover").html("");
        }
    );
});
```

With `$(document).ready(...);` your javascript code will wait for DOM and if it's completely loaded it will start.

http://jsfiddle.net/8as30y06/

Comment: I tried this. I see that the code is working in the fiddle. I think the code is correct. Do you know what other errors could be possible? I'm new to this stuff :(

Comment: @SriRamGopal Open your web inspector in your browser and see what's going on in the console...

Answer (score 0):

Your script does actually work: http://jsfiddle.net/g2n403zs/ . Are you sure you are loading jquery before you are calling it's functions? What does the error console say?

```
$(".logo").hover( 
    function() { $("#span_hover").html("Please visit http://www.gmu.edu for more information.") }, 
    function() { $("#span_hover").html(""); } );
```

Comment: the text does not appear when I hover

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work ( you were missing a semicolon)

Here is fiddle:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/uct2qLop/)

```
$(".logo").hover(function() { 
$("#span_hover").html("Please visit http://www.gmu.edu for more information."); }, 
function() { $("#span_hover").html(""); });
```